# Why laptop reboots after electrostatic discharge

Tags: discharge, laptop, electrostatic

So why does this happens when my laptop is plugged to the charger? Typical charger scheme looks like this:
[image]

What is the path for discharge current? Low voltage part seems to be isolated from power lines.

Some forums says that the reason the laptop was not connected to the grounded outlet but how can grounding helps?

Comment: Your question mentions ESD. Then you ask about a charger **why** and **how would that be related to ESD**. You make assumptions about power supply isolation stopping ESD discharge, it does not work like that. In general your question is too broad, you're making wild assumptions. You should describe the behavior that you see without making assumptions (like that it is related to the power supply).

Comment: Try this experiment by replacing your charger with a capacitor: connect a capacitor from laptop common to ground whose value is similar to the capacitance across the pale dotted-line barrier in your charger schematic - see if ESD still causes reboot.

Comment: I think this question is fine and interesting, VTO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually a typical modern "isolated" charger schematic looks probably more like this: -

[image]

Note the 2.2nF capacitor connecting output terminals back to the rectified non-isolated supply. It is present to cut-down on EMC on the output and will of course be a pretty good path for a discharge of current to the AC wiring and hence earth.

> What is the path for dicharge current? Low voltage part seems to be
>   isolated from power lines.

Not on a modern power supply - static discharges will fly through the aforementioned capacitor.